# Take picture image loading issue in Samsung device 4 and 5

Tags: android

The Code runs properly but the Samsung device(Version 4 and 5) is created a problem the image takes a camera and a load of imageview this not load the image in android Application.

***Code:***

```
Bitmap profilebitmap=null;  

public void openCameraForProfile(){
          Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 101);//camera open and intent onActivityResult.
    }
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
           if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try{
                   Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");


                  iv_profile.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                    profilebitmap = thumbnail;
            }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
          }
```

Comment: What is version 4 and 5?

Comment: Samsung device version 4 and version 5

Comment: What is device version 4 and 5?

Answer (score 0):

```
app gradle

          implementation 'com.fxn769:pix:1.4.4'

 place in to your activity for you click button for take picture 
       private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1001;

          Options options = Options.init()
          .setRequestCode(PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST)                                                     
          //Request code for activity results
          .setCount(3)                                                         
          //Number of images to restict selection count
          .setFrontfacing(false)                                                
          //Front Facing camera on start

          .setImageQuality(ImageQuality.HIGH)                                
         //Image Quality
          .setPreSelectedUrls(returnValue)               
        //Preselected Image Urls
          .setScreenOrientation(Options.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)                
        //Orientaion
          .setPath("/pix/images");                                             
       //Custom Path For Image Storage

        Pix.start(MainActivity.this, options);

receive 
           public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
          {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
                    ArrayList<String> selectedPaths =  
                         data.getStringArrayListExtra(Pix.IMAGE_RESULTS);
                    if (selectedPaths != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedPaths.size(); i++) {
                            String fPath = selectedPaths.get(i);
                            if (!returnValue.contains(fPath)) {
                                Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fPath));
                                getImage(fileUri, fPath);
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 show image

         private void getImage(Uri fileUri, String mFilePath) {
        try {
            if (fileUri != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = 
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), 
        fileUri);
                bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 1080);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }

resize the image
        public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        if (width > maxSize || height > maxSize) {
            float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
            if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
                width = maxSize;
                height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
            } else {
                height = maxSize;
                width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
            }
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
        } else {
            return image;
        }
      }
```